# How can I fix my dice loss calculation during the training process of a convolutional neural network implemented in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am implementing my own code using keras to do semantic segmentation. My testing images has shape `(10, 512, 512, 5)`, where 10 is the number of images, 512 is their size and 5 is the number of classes I want to segment. As last activation function I use softmax and as loss I want to extract the dice loss (https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04797) in order to improve the segmentation results. My code is:

```
eps = 1e-3

def dice(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.one_hot(K.argmax(y_pred,axis=-1), Nclasses) 
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    num = 2*K.sum(y_true_f*y_pred_f)
    den = K.sum(K.square(y_true_f))+K.sum(K.square(y_pred_f))+eps
    return num/den

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-dice(y_true, y_pred)
```

I use `K.one_hot(K.argmax(...))` because in this way my `y_pred` is binary and not made by probabilities (right?).
Anyway, when the training process starts, I receive this error:

> ```
> "ValueError: An operation has None for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval."
> ```

Comment: What are the dimensions of `y_true` and `y_pred`? The paper you have cited computes dice loss over volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code snippet for your dice coefficient.
Important observation : If you have your masks one-hot-encoded, this code should also work for multi-class segmentation.

```
smooth = 1.

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)


def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I had a similar code before but I was wondering if I should do something on that y_pred, because I think it is made by probabilities and not 0s and 1s.
Anyway, I use `to_categorical` for my ground-truth, so that one of them is (512, 512, 5), where 5 is the number of classes and all of those images are binary.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Since all the images are binary and you have a 3D-Block with width x height x number_of_classes, where each slice of a block width x height x 1 corresponds to a class, you have only 0's and 1's. So that is why the code should work :D, exactly like you said.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11157) seems to indicate that since `argmax` does not have a gradient in keras, you will not be able to use it in your custom loss function.